# What is the best way to structure password storing tables in RDBMS?

Tags: rdbms, password-protection

Name of an account and it's password are stored in different tables in order to improve security. Which table should contain a foreign key to another?

I can store passwords like this:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
      id   INT
    , name TEXT
)
;

CREATE TABLE password
(
      account_id    INT
    , password_hash TEXT
    , CONSTRAINT fk_password_account_id
        FOREING KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (id)
)
;
```

In that way hacker don't know user's password even if she/he knows account's name.

Another approach is:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
      id          INT
    , name        TEXT
    , password_id INT
    , CONSTRAINT fk_account_password_id
        FOREIGN KEY (password_id) REFERENCES password (id)
)
;

CREATE TABLE password
(
      id            INT
    , password_hash TEXT
)
;
```

This way even if hacker knows a password, she/he doesn't know who is the owner.

So, which approach is better, assuming passwords are stored in different databases, or, at least, different schemas? And if passwords and account are stored in the same database?

Comment: Not as text, I'd assume. But I don't see any harm in (individually salted) hashed passwords being stored on the same table as the account name. If the attacker has access to your tables, then they could do the lookup themselves -- so you gain nothing by separating them.

Comment: So this only makes sense if passwords are held in different database?